# jQuery - detect no action for 'x' minutes and run function on that event (no event in X minutes)

Tags: jquery

How to detect that user have done nothing for 'X' minute and run function on this event?

E.G.

`if( // no action from user for 'X' minutes) { //do stuff }` ??

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/WaHkG/3/)**

Like everyone else has stated use `setTimeout` and set it to the desired amount of time to wait. If there is any activity just clear the timeout using `clearTimeout`.

```
// If theres no activity for 5 seconds do something
var activityTimeout = setTimeout(inActive, 5000);

function resetActive(){
    $(document.body).attr('class', 'active');
    clearTimeout(activityTimeout);
    activityTimeout = setTimeout(inActive, 5000);
}

// No activity do something.
function inActive(){
    $(document.body).attr('class', 'inactive');
}

// Check for mousemove, could add other events here such as checking for key presses ect.
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(){resetActive()});
```

Comment: great example! Working perfectly!

Answer (score 6):

Set a timeout for `X` minutes.

In the `<body>`'s keydown and mousemove events, clear the timeout and set it again.

Comment: +1, just make sure all keydown and mousemove events bubble up to the top of the DOM tree, be careful if you call `e.stopPropagation()` on any of those events in your document.

Comment: @Darth: Or, if you do, just re-set the timeout again.

Comment: Well, yes, that's what I was trying to say, just left out the most important bit of my suggestion. :) That reminds me, it would be a nice addition to jQuery to globally listen to events, either on the top of the tree or even if something calls `stopPropagation()`.